# Is there a simple way to build a stacked bar chart in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which uses pandas to build a stacked bar chart:

```
dfTech = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018],
                       'Other': [48.2,44.8,151.2,54.3,185,253.7,418.6,650,915], 
                       'Graphcore':[0,0,0,0,0,0,30,80,200], 
                       'Medopad Ltd':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,120],
                       'BenevolentAI Limited': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,115], 
                       'Blippar.Com': [0,0,0,0,0,45,54,0,63], 
                       'Draktrace': [0,0,0,0,0,40.5,65,75,50], 
                       'The Hut Group Limited': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,168.9,0]})



dfTech.loc[:,['Other',  'Graphcore',    'Medopad Ltd',  'BenevolentAI Limited', 
              'Blippar.Com',    'Darktrace',    
              'The Hut Group Limited']].plot.bar(stacked=True,  figsize=(10,7))
```

Which produces this which is exactly what I want:

[image]

However, I am trying to always stick to the same format with my code i.e. always use matplotlib, and always seperate out the fig and ax i.e:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (9,4.2), dpi = 120)
    ax.bar(dfBar2['X'], dfBar2['value'], edgecolor = 'black',color = colors)
    ...
```

Is there an easy way of doing a stacked bar chart through my method? The examples I have found end up using `enumerate` or `for` loops which seems way too convoluted and surely cannot be the best way of doing a simple stacked bar chart in matplotlib (especially as Pandas does it in one line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a workaround using pandas by putting `ax=ax` in my pandas plot, seems to be a lot better than the other examples I found building stacked bar charts in matplotlib:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (7,5), dpi = 120)

dfTech.loc[:,['Other',  'Graphcore',    'Medopad Ltd',  'BenevolentAI Limited', 
              'Blippar.Com',    'Darktrace',    
              'The Hut Group Limited']].plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, figsize=(10,7))

ax.set_xticklabels(['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017', 
                    '2018'], weight = 'bold',fontsize = 9)
ax.set_yticklabels(['0','200','400','600','800','1000', '1200', '1400'], 
                   weight = 'bold',fontsize = 9)

ax.set_ylabel('Private Investments ($m)', fontsize = 11, labelpad = 20, 
              fontdict=dict(weight='bold')) 



etc.........
```

Still not sure if there is way of doing this easily through matplotlib, without having to use the Pandas `plot.bar` etc, but at least it works for me.

[image]